# Production prefix not working on makeStyles classNames

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, monorepo, lerna

I am using **createGenerateClassName** for added prefix to className in Material-UI component used in federated library/module of **lerna** mono-repo.

```
import { createGenerateClassName, StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core'

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
      seed: 'xyz',
      productionPrefix: 'abc-',
    })

function Header() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
         ...
    </StylesProvider>
  )
}
```

But prefix is not getting added to classes made using **makeStyles** in production build mode. Although prefix is getting added to Mui classes.

[image]

Comment: Please try with `from '@material-ui/core/styles`